# Does Spring override try catch in the controller class with the SimpleExceptionResolver

Tags: spring-mvc

I am planning to use SimpleExceptionResolver for handling most generic exceptions like unhandled runtime exceptions. e.g. NullPointerException, NumberFormatException etc. and wil redirect to common error jsp

However in the controller I would catch the application specific exceptions like custom exceptions.

My question is : 
  Lets say if SimpleExceptionResolver is configured to catch the Exception class, will it override the controller level catch stattements and catch all the excptions instead. My guess is, SimpleExceptionResolver does not give opportunity to the Controller class to handle any custom exception.

Kindly provide valuable suggestions and workarounds thnks

Comment: Can you show a more concrete example of what your problems is? Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Hi @Markus Malkusch I have not tried yet I am in the design phase. I am planning to handle project custom exceptions in the controller. Any point of time if runtime exception occures;lets assume NumberFormatException it should go to the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. However my fear is if SimpleMappingExceptionResolver is configured to resolve "Exception" or "Throwable" then it will also catch the custom execeptions as in overrrding the controller try/catch. I think I should have more specific RuntimeExceptions configured for the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver right ?

Comment: @TechiVibe The time you spent for this conversation is sufficient to evaluate the behaviour. The point is I don't know it fur sure, but my feeling says that a Exception is caught only once and the `ExceptionResolver` will be at the end of the line. But to be certain I would have to try that out by myself. So this task goes to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using try catch(Exception e) block,in your controller,that means you are already handling the exception,inside your controller classes.It will not be handled by HandlerExceptionResolver class.Only those exception which can not be caught inside the controller are propagated to HandlerExceptionResolver.

I would suggest in case of exception in your controller classes,you can use try catch block,and from catch block you can throw your own custom exception,which will be propagated to SimpleMappingExceptionResolver,and there you can prepare response message as per the exception type and cause.

Comment: I assume OP's about [`@ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

Comment: @Markus what OP stands for??

Comment: @Code_Craker thanks for the reply. I am planning to handle project custom exceptions in the controller. Any point of time if runtime exception e..g occures lets assume NumberFormatException it should go to the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver. However my fear is if SimpleMappingExceptionResolver is configured to resolve Exception then it will also catch the custom execeptions as in overrrding the controller try/catch. I think I should have more specific RuntimeExceptions configured for the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver  right ?